# Can cookies be used to access an account like Instagram

Tags: security, cookie

Edit: Please don't downvote the post, I meant to click the Super User stackExchange when clicking the bookmark in my browser.

Can cookies.txt obtained via 'Get cookies.txt' chrome extension when you're logged in be used to access your account.

Comment: Closing this in favor of https://superuser.com/q/1663095/513541

Answer (score 1):

This is offtopic in the context of this stack exchange website but, yes, cookies can be used. Actually it's how most websites store your credentials to recognize you later when you visit website again.

Stealing cookies is often used by criminals to get access to accounts they are interested in because doing so is easier than e.g. hacking two-factor authorization which requires access to e.g. the user's smartphone.

Comment: Omg, when clicking on the bookmark in my browser I meant to click the Super User. Thank you though